# Prisma: How to select or include on a Group by?

Tags: database, postgresql, prisma

I have a table called `financial_transaction` which have data like this:

| id | debit | credit | financial_type | payment_id | payment | author_id | author |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 150 | 0 | Payment | 2 | - | 1 | - |
| 2 | 0 | 50 | Payment | 2 | - | 1 | - |

so my desire from this data is to:

- **Group it by `payment_id`.**
- **Include true to `author`.**
- **Sum all the `debits` and `credits`.**
- **Display fields like `financial_type` and  `payment_id`.**

So here is what I want:

```
[
   { 
     payment_id: 2,
     author: {
       first_name: John,
       last_name: Doe
     }
     debit: 150,
     credit: 50,
     financial_type: Payment
   }
]
```

also here's my Prisma Scehma:

```
enum FinancialType {
  Payment
  Expense
  Withdraw
}
```

**User Table**

```
model User {
  id                             Int                @id @default(autoincrement())
  first_name                     String
  last_name                      String
  saved_payments                 Payment[]
  saved_financial_transactions FinancialTransaction[]
}
```

**Payment Table**

```
model Payment {
  id                     Int                @id @default(autoincrement())
  payed_price            Decimal
  remaining_price        Decimal?
  price_per_month        Decimal
  financial_transactions FinancialTransaction[]
  author                 User?              @relation(fields: [author_id], references: [id])
  author_id           Int?
}
```

**FinancialTransaction Table**

```
model FinancialTransaction {
  id                  Int                @id @default(autoincrement())
  debit               Decimal
  credit              Decimal
  financial_type      FinancialType
  payment             Payment            @relation(fields: [payment_id], references: [id])
  payment_id          Int
  author              User?              @relation(fields: [author_id], references: [id])
  author_id           Int?

}
```

I tried to get this with the prisma `groupBy` like in the following:

```
const financia_transactions = wait prisma.$queryRaw`select jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(t)) from
        (
          select payment_id,
                  jsonb_build_object('first_name', u.first_name, 'second_name', u.second_name) author,
                  sum(debit) debit, 
                  sum(credit) credit, 
                  max(financial_type) financial_type,
          from "FinancialTransaction" as ft join "User" u on ft.author_id = u.id
          group by payment_id
        ) t;`;
```

but this is not working...
So my question is there a way Prisma can do the trick and get me this?

Answer (score 4):

My solution was to make 2 queries to my database and then do 2 `for` loops to match the data:

```
const aggregate = await prisma.expenses.groupBy({
    by: ['category_id'],
    where: {
        userId: user.id,
        month: parseInt(req.body.month),
        year: parseInt(req.body.year),
    },
    _sum: {
        amount: true,
    },
})
const categories = await prisma.budget.findMany({
    where: {
        userId: user.id,
    },
    select: {
        id: true,
        category: true,
    }
})
const summary = [];
for (let i = 0; i < aggregate.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < categories.length; j++) {
        if (aggregate[i].category_id == categories[j].id) {
            let element = {
                ...aggregate[i],
                category: categories[j].category,
            }
            summary.push(element);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as of Prisma 4.8.x this is still unsupported.  See this Github issue for a response:

https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/6517

This will hopefully be a feature implemented in the future, but in the meantime you may want to consider using `queryRaw` since it won't have those constraints, though you'll want to bear in mind the normal drawbacks of the raw queries.

https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access

Answer (score 0):

Use a native query.

```sql
select jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(t)) from
(
 select payment_id, 
        jsonb_build_object('first_name', u.first_name, 'second_name', u.second_name) author, 
        sum(debit) debit, 
        sum(credit) credit, 
        max(financial_type) financial_type
 from financial_transaction ft join "user" u on ft.author_id = u.id
 group by payment_id
) t;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer bro but it's saying `column \"author\" does not exist`.... I might remind you if you in somehow worked with primsa that this author from user table. which means `have 1-many relationship with paymnets` that's why I left empty in the above table

Comment: btw `author` column has all the user data as a object.

Comment: Well then, prisma or not, `join` is knocking on the door. Answer updated. BTW it would be better and easier if you add your tables' schema in the question.

Comment: Still I have this new error `db error: ERROR: column reference \"author_id\" is ambiguous`. where you thing the problem is?

Comment: Pls send me your query and your tables structure

Comment: Bro, I have updated the question and passed all things you requested... please check

Comment: Well, these are prisma-specific. Sorry, I am afraid that I can not help.

Comment: you did what you could. Thank you btw!

Answer (score 0):

I have done that using the following:

```
const { PrismaClient } = require('@prisma/client')
const prisma = new PrismaClient()

const execute = async () => {
  const tr = await prisma.financialTransaction.create({
    data: {
      debit: 150,
      credit: 0,
      financialType: 'payment',
      paymentId: 2,
      author: {
        create: {
          name: 'John Doe',
        }
      }
    },
    include: {
      author: true
    }
  })
  await prisma.financialTransaction.create({
    data: {
      debit: 0,
      credit: 50,
      financialType: 'payment',
      paymentId: 2,
      author: {
        connect: {
          id: tr.author.id
        }
      }
    }
  })

  console.log(JSON.stringify(await prisma.financialTransaction.findMany({ include: { author: true } }), null, 2));

  const groupTransactions = await prisma.financialTransaction.groupBy({
    by: ['financialType', 'paymentId', 'authorId'],
    _sum: {
      credit: true,
      debit: true,
    },
  })

  console.log(groupTransactions);
};

execute();
```

Using this schema

```
datasource mysql {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

model FinancialTransaction {
  id            Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  debit         Int
  credit        Int
  financialType String
  paymentId     Int
  author        Author @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  authorId      Int
}

model Author {
  id           Int                    @id @default(autoincrement())
  name         String
  transactions FinancialTransaction[] @relation
}
```

and here you go the output

[image]

Comment: why are you creating data, I just want to fetch not insert

Comment: It is for showing an example :)

Answer (score 0):

Prisma supports raw queries - https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access#raw-queries-with-mongodb

So in case of MongoDB, via the `aggregateRaw` method you can use a native query to

1. $group - to group by some property
2. $match - only included groups of 2 or more(can skip this step)
3. $lookup - to include the data you need

For example:

```
await prisma.stake.aggregateRaw({
    pipeline: [
        {
            $group:
            /**
             * _id: The id of the group.
             * fieldN: The first field name.
             */
            {
                _id: "$ownerAddress",
                // Count number of matching docs for the group
                count: {
                    $sum: 1,
                },
                // Save the _id for matching docs
                docs: {
                    $push: "$_id",
                },
            },
        },
        {
            $match:
            /**
             * query: The query in MQL.
             */
            {
                count: {
                    $gt: 1,
                },
            },
        },
        {
            $lookup:
            /**
             * from: The target collection.
             * localField: The local join field.
             * foreignField: The target join field.
             * as: The name for the results.
             * pipeline: Optional pipeline to run on the foreign collection.
             * let: Optional variables to use in the pipeline field stages.
             */
            {
                from: "target",
                localField: "localField",
                foreignField: "foreignField",
                as: "included",
            },
        },
    ]
})
```

Just replace the names of the fields with the one you need and you're good to go!

P.S. You can use even more complex aggregations, basically anything which mongoDB supports. And you can build those aggregations with MongoDB Compass, which has a nice built-in editor.
[image: built-in aggregation editor]

Answer (score 0):

I came here with the same question and it seems like there isn't support at the Prisma level for this feature yet. In the meantime, I'm doing what I figured is the least inefficient approach.

In my case, I needed to see the users with the most number of audit trail events in the system.

```js
    const mostActiveUsers = await Prisma.serverAuditTrailEvent.groupBy({
        by: ['actorId'],
        _count: true,
        orderBy: {
            _count: {
                actorId: 'desc',
            },
        },
        take: 10
    });
    //match users to actorId
    const matchingUsers = await Prisma.userAccount.findMany({
        where: {
            id: {
                in: mostActiveUsers.map(x => x.actorId)
            }
        },
        select: {
            username: true,
            deleted: true,
            id: true
        }
    });

    const userIdHash = matchingUsers.reduce((acc, cur) => ({ ...acc, [cur.id]: cur}), {});
    //send to frontend however you wish
    return res.status(200).json({
        mostUsedEndpoints,
        mostActiveUsers: mostActiveUsers.map(x => ({
            ...x,
            actorUser: userIdHash[x.actorId]
        }))
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

It is achievable. First you groupBy then map the result to include the author:

```
    const groupTransactions = await prisma.financialTransaction.groupBy({
        by: ['financialType', 'paymentId', 'authorId'],
        _sum: {
        credit: true,
        debit: true,
      },
    }).map((d) => {
       const author = await prisma.author.findFirst({where: {id: d.authorId}});
       return {...d, author}
   });
```

Comment: Won't this lead to a lot of database calls if the data being mapped is huge?

Comment: @ArchNoob is right - while this might still "feel" instant, it will consume quite a lot of bandwidth. To make matters worse, `.map()` is not async-friendly, meaning the promises might not necessarily resolve by that point. You can still use it by means of not awaiting inside it and doing `Promise.all()` on the outside.